# Video Streaming, allow streaming only through the Player and prevent download

Tags: video, streaming

I m working on a video streaming application. The application is ready and working well. In the final check I m visualizing a scenario where a valid user can download the video rather than playing at player.

I want to prevent the download and allow streaming via player. I m not worried about screen capture and other methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a streaming server like red5
http://red5.org/
you cannot disallow stream download without a true streaming server.
you can host you video on a streaming service too ( no server set up , but a fee according to the bandwith ).