# Can I make a video-stream not downloadable (by using tricks inside the code)

Tags: html, web-services, video-streaming

I have used to download any video content from using some programs (like [Internet Download Manager (IDM)](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) that has never failed before).

Being a beginner of webdesign I'm wondered if there is a way to protect my video from downloading while it is streaming, or if there is a trick to slip away at least from this Internet Download Manager.

Comment: Have you seen the many duplicates? [Protect flash video from download/right protect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/300749/367456); [Prevent HTML5 video from being downloaded (right-click saved)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9756837/367456); [Prevent Video downloading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4582433/367456); **[How to stop IDM from grabbing video/audio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12802862/367456)**; [Video Streaming, allow streaming only through the Player and prevent download](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4767146/367456) and the many more? - Especially the bold one looks like an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are hosting the video on your server/shared server**

Place the embedding code in an external JavaScript file. This makes the video file difficult to find. Write this JavaScript by splitting up the location of the video into different variables spread throughout the code, or by referencing variables from other JavaScript files used elsewhere in the web page). This will just make downloading difficult, but not impossible.

**Use a streaming server:**

These make it almost impossible to download but the cost of signing up with them is generally very high.
Examples of streaming servers:
[RealNetworks Managed Application Services (MAS)](http://www.realnetworks.com/products-services/)
[Apple Quicktime Streaming Services](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/extending/resources.html)
[Macromedia Communication Server Hosts](http://www.adobe.com/partners/flashcom/)